# Jpa , Hibernate select query optimization

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I am new to JPa / Hibernate.
We are using JPA with hibernate in our application.
Currently i observed that performing select query on table with criteria, hibernate perform select query for each row.

So my question is , how hibernate perform search on table and retrieves records ?

I have a scenario where i need to find active users
and perform filers on active user list , like recently logged in users, most popular user(based on some criteria)  for example 
i have 100 active users of which 
20 users are recently logged in.
20 users are most popular.

if i have to fetch records from database ,
when i query with active users , hibernate perform 100 select operations.(with table scan)

and 
if i perform 2 seperate queries for recent and most popular users 
hibernate will perform 20 + 20 = 40 select operations. (but with 2 times table scan)

**so how hibernate fetches records from database ?**
if i compare with jdbc , i would say by getting active pitches and performing filters on it i will be doing 1 time table scan.

but with hibernate it performs more select operations and it queries less select when i do individual selects for recent and most popular users ,even when i do 2 time table scan !

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name = "fk_profile_id", referencedColumnName = "pk_id")
private Profile Profile;

@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "investmentPitch", targetEntity = InvestmentType.class, orphanRemoval = true)
private List<InvestmentType> investmentType;

@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "investmentPitch", targetEntity = TabDetail.class, orphanRemoval = true)
private List<TabDetail> TabDetail;

@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "investmentPitch", targetEntity = Address.class, orphanRemoval = true)
private List<Address> Address;

@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.DETACH)
@JoinTable(name = "pitch_sector", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "fk_id", nullable = false, updatable = false) }, inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "fk_sector_id", nullable = false, updatable = false) })
private List<SectorMaster> sectors;
```

Comment: Could you please post your mappings and classes. Hibernate definitly doesn't retrieve every record with a single select. There must be some mapping (for example one to many) that is loaded for every single record after the record list is loaded.

Comment: i have updated my mapping objects ... it mainly has oneToMany and ManyToMany relations... when i perform select on above mentioned table (investmentPitch) it queries every single record with select query

Comment: FetchType.EAGER will load things on initialisation, generally, this is not what you want to be doing.

Comment: Could you test and remove the FetchType.EAGER from the profile? I think that this triggers a select for every loaded user to load the profile.

Comment: thanks for your reply ... actually i want profile to be loaded everytime when i fetch user, but my actual question is : when i perform select on table , i am expecting a list in return by calling "query.getResultList()" so i am expecting one select query , but hibernate performs select for individual records ? why is it so ?

Comment: I don't think that hibernate performs a single query for every User. It performs a single query for every Profile as you configured EAGER-fetching. Have a look at my answer.

Comment: yes ... i closely debug the queries , it showed me that it performed single select on parent table and one select for each profile due to eager loading. thanks for your help. now i feel relief :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The FetchType.EAGER causes hibernate to load the profile directly after the User is loaded. This triggers a select for every User.

You can change this to LAZY. Then the select is only triggered if you first access the profile object. If you have to access the profile of every selected user this would also cause a select for every user. To avoid this you can preload the profile together with the user in one single select. For detailed information about this see the following links: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/querycriteria.html#querycriteria-dynamicfetching and http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/performance.html#performance-fetching